# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api, pycocotools

I have problems when installing TensorFlow with object detection API.
I am follow the step in this URL: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md

The step:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install
```

The error that I got which is pycocotools builds erro

```
Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pycocotools
      copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pycocotools
      copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pycocotools
      copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pycocotools
      copying pycocotools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\pycocotools
      running build_ext
      skipping 'pycocotools\_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
      building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
  Building wheel for crcmod (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for crcmod: filename=crcmod-1.7-py3-none-any.whl size=18834 sha256=f81bd6fe750138daa391b2214a9304fb6ad9919f8e387323ac98770b0aa3c232
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7zr_bch5\wheels\ca\5a\02\f3acf982a026f3319fb3e798a8dca2d48fafee7761788562e9
  Building wheel for dill (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for dill: filename=dill-0.3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl size=78628 sha256=75f647cd694be489e90d86ef98dff772eedb027b3f896ca6370b61ea29d7dfce
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7zr_bch5\wheels\07\35\78\e9004fa30578734db7f10e7a211605f3f0778d2bdde38a239d
  Building wheel for kaggle (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for kaggle: filename=kaggle-1.5.12-py3-none-any.whl size=73031 sha256=8d131b867ba05b1c4a2e1e1a49563d5914cb7b33f36f68a8128904c720331ea6
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7zr_bch5\wheels\29\da\11\144cc25aebdaeb4931b231e25fd34b394e6a5725cbb2f50106
  Building wheel for py-cpuinfo (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for py-cpuinfo: filename=py_cpuinfo-8.0.0-py3-none-any.whl size=22243 sha256=92746edde55411f7346e17ee63ca616212930c5fa5f005036aef965dd9baca06
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7zr_bch5\wheels\57\cb\6d\bab2257f26c5be4a96ff65c3d2a7122c96529b73773ee37f36
  Building wheel for seqeval (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for seqeval: filename=seqeval-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl size=16165 sha256=d985a9f1092a64367568bcf2bb648003c4ccc7387750cf64298f1c5b7516075a
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7zr_bch5\wheels\ad\5c\ba\05fa33fa5855777b7d686e843ec07452f22a66a138e290e732
  Building wheel for termcolor (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for termcolor: filename=termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=4832 sha256=4caa3ff6ab601564aa03dfbaed490fd0470481d2ccd75c4c4aad8a76dfb57ce8
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7zr_bch5\wheels\a0\16\9c\5473df82468f958445479c59e784896fa24f4a5fc024b0f501
  Building wheel for docopt (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for docopt: filename=docopt-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=13706 sha256=c91a22c0b5638b26b0a5eb72354fafae0c1db8d5281ecedb5db105e2b9ac4dec
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7zr_bch5\wheels\56\ea\58\ead137b087d9e326852a851351d1debf4ada529b6ac0ec4e8c
  Building wheel for promise (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for promise: filename=promise-2.3-py3-none-any.whl size=21486 sha256=85eb3ac751ef78bcf8214c5ec38acebf3ec316ef989990477b98d3798fddd751
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\ainul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7zr_bch5\wheels\54\aa\01\724885182f93150035a2a91bce34a12877e8067a97baaf5dc8
Successfully built object-detection avro-python3 crcmod dill kaggle py-cpuinfo seqeval termcolor docopt promise
Failed to build pycocotools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am using conda enviroment. This is my build version

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2022.4.26            haa95532_0
certifi                   2022.5.18.1      py38haa95532_0
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.22.4                   pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1o               h2bbff1b_0
p5py                      1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pep517                    0.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.1.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pkgconfig                 1.5.5                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.8.8                hdbf39b2_5
setuptools                62.4.0                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.38.3               h2bbff1b_0
tomli                     2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2              py38haa95532_2
```

Answer (score 11):

hope it's not too late.

I was having the same problem, what I did, and solved it:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

And then make sure that you build pycocotools, as in:

```
pip install cython

git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git

cd cocoapi/PythonAPI
make
cp -r pycocotools <PATH_TO_TF>/TensorFlow/models/research/
```

Reset your terminal and try to install it again

Finally test your installation, from research:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

You should see something like this:

Ran 24 tests in 33.388s

OK (skipped=1)

Comment: how to find PATH_TO_TF?

Comment: I came across this trying to install segment-geospatial.  I only had to to the first step i.e, ```sudo apt install gcc```and then re-run ```pip install segment-geospatial ```

Answer (score 11):

- This error comes when python development package is not installed.
- python-dev package contains the header files you need to build Python extensions.

To install the python-dev package, run the below mentioned command:

```
sudo apt install python3.x-dev
```

x: minor version of python

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: This solution worked for me

Answer (score 2):

try this mate
`pip install pycocotools-windows`
if you are using win platform

or

````
conda install cython before
pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#egg=pycocotools^&subdirectory=PythonAPI```
````

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pycocotools-windows (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pycocotools-windows

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and managed to fix it another way!
I downloaded Visual Studio with C/C++. The following link will take you to the website to download the program:
[C/C++ download](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/).
I then restarted my computer and it seemed to work.

Answer (score -2):

This Helped me while installing Detectron2 library.

```
!pip install pycocotools-fix
```